# Calling a class method in another class - Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am using Tkinter in Python 3 to create a converter between hex, binary and denary - while creating my own methods for conversions instead of using the built in methods.

I've completed the denary to binary conversion through the use of my 'highestPowerOf2' method in the DenToBin class. I want to use this method in my HexToBin class, but whenever I try to, an additional blank window pops up and I receive - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title' - error.

How would I run 'highestPowerOf2' in the HexToBin class?

(also sorry for any poor programming practise)

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class Menu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master= None): # initialise Menu
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # initialise Frame
        self.master = master # what does this do
        self.createWindow()

    def createWindow(self):
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        denToBin = Button(self, text = 'Denary to Binary', command = lambda: self.changeWindow(DenToBin))
        denToBin.pack(fill = X, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        hexToBin = Button(self, text = 'Hex to Binary', command = lambda: self.changeWindow(HexToBin))
        hexToBin.pack(fill = X, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    def changeWindow(self, object):
        root.withdraw()
        currentFrame = object(root)

class DenToBin(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.Window()
        self.denary = 0

    def Window(self):
       # print(self.denary) -- Why is this not recognised?????????
        self.master.title('Unit Converter: Denary to Binary')
        instructionDen = Label(self, text = 'Denary Value: ')
        instructionDen.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10)

        instructionBin = Label(self, text = 'Binary Value: ')
        instructionBin.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10)

        self.denaryEntry = Entry(self)
        self.denaryEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 5)

        convertButton = Button(self, text = 'Convert!', command = lambda: self.highestPowerOf2(10)) # as an example
        convertButton.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    # finds highest power of 2 that is less than denary number - helps self.convert()
    def highestPowerOf2(self,number):
        print('I find the highest power of 2 that fits into the number given.')


class HexToBin(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.Window()
        self.denary = 0

    def Window(self):
        self.master.title('Unit Converter: Hexadecimal to Binary')
        instructionHex = Label(self, text = 'Hexadecimal Value: ')
        instructionHex.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10)

        instructionBin = Label(self, text = 'Binary Value: ')
        instructionBin.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10)

        self.hexadecimalEntry = Entry(self)
        self.hexadecimalEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 5)

        convertButton = Button(self, text = 'Convert!', command = self.convert)
        convertButton.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    def convert(self):
        # I need to call the 'highestPowerOf2' method here.
        pass

root = Tk()
unitConverter = Menu(root) # root is master
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be best if you could replace the code with a [mcve]. There's a lot of code in your post that is not directly related to the question being asked.

Comment: DenToBin.highestPowerOf2() should work. Dosent it?

Comment: @BryanOakley I've removed unneeded code, hopefully it should be a minimal reproducible ex now. If not, let me know.

Comment: @Atlas435 I tried this with `DenToBin.highestPowerOf2(10)` in my convert method in HexToBin but received the error: TypeError: highestPowerOf2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'. Thank you for answering my other questions though!

Comment: @StudyAccount you need to call it in this case like this "x = DenToBin.highestPowerOf2(10)" cause x will be the argument self, 10 the argument number. Also because you return a value, x become the value that is returned.

Comment: @StudyAccount You may interessted in this for a better understanding what happens here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8NDKzCl0Mc&list=PL6lxxT7IdTxFKo9DguLxGM2dhgb8-u976&index=90&app=desktop

Comment: @Atlas435 thank you for the video, the series seems really good! Thanks to you and BryanOakley I was able to solve the issue (which brings up a separate issue) - but my question here has been solved.